# Could not find the controller_interface package

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This was working, I have just realized that  it is failing:

roslaunch rrobt__gazebo rrbot.launch

[FATAL] [1378739384.640356370, 0.219000000]: Failed to create robot simulation interface loader: rospack could not find the controller_interface package containing controller_interface::ControllerBase

Using Ubuntu 12.04, ros_hydro from deb, and gazebo-1.9.1 from source.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4288/could-not-find-the-controller_interface-package/) by [rguzman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/353/rguzman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have solved installing sources of :

ros_control
ros_controllers

and repeated catkin_make / catkin_make install

---

Originally posted by [rguzman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/353/rguzman/) with karma: 16 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0